# windows phone sending values with http client GET method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-get, dotnet-httpclient

I've managed the sending values with POST method like the following.

```
 var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "user"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "password"),
        }; var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("URL", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
```

But now the method where i send the request is a GET and i need to send values like the POST to get the response otherwise it returns an error.
can anyone help of how to send values with GET method ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a simple

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("URL?username=user&password=password");
```

?

Comment: Yeah it worked :P
im new to httpClient library and stuff.
thank you very much :D